# Installed fonts are not viewable on my machine

Tags: fonts

I am building a website and just noticed that common web fonts are not viewable in my browsers.

There are numerous fonts installed in /usr/share/fonts. There are folders for cmap, truetype, opentype, type1 and X11. All of the fonts in those folders are installed. But when I try to build a page and use those fonts specifically, they are not viewable or usable.  They are also not viewable on my machine anywhere. It seems my whole machine, including browsers, only use 3 fonts, one generic serif, one generic sans-serif and one generic monospace. That's it.

The installed fonts only seem to work in LibreOffice and MuseScore (a music writing program)

How do I make the installed fonts viewable in my browsers to view my webpages?

I already know how to use Google Fonts. I want to know how to use the fonts already on my machine, and fonts that would already be on other people's machines.

Comment: In FF there is the font option "Allow pages to show their own fonts, instead of your selection above". Is that option selected? (Assuming that other browsers have similar options.)

Comment: Thank you. I was unaware of those settings. I adjusted settings in both Chrome and Firefox. I used this site to test: https://www.w3.org/Style/Examples/007/fonts.en.html . With setting adjustments, some variations are viewable in Firefox. Nearly none of them are viewable in Chrome.